# Открывать таб по соответсвующему id

Tags: css, tab

На сайте реализованы табы (вкладки). Можно лив этом коде сделать так, чтобы каждый таб имел свой уникальный id в урл? То есть, если в адресную строку ввести http://sitename/#master-klassu открывалась сразу вкладка с мастер-классами.

```css
div.tab-frame input {
    display: none;
}

div.tab-frame label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #979797;
    border: 0;
    padding: 8px 12px 25px 0px;
    margin: 15px 80px 0 0;
}

div.tab-frame label span {
    color: #00aeef
}

div.tab-frame label:hover {
    color: #00aeef
}

div.tab-frame input:checked+label {
    color: #333333;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00aeef;
    cursor: default;
}

div.tab-frame label.disable:hover {
    color: #979797;
    cursor: default;
}

div.tab-frame div.tab {
    display: none;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    clear: left;
}

div.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.tab:nth-of-type(1),
div.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.tab:nth-of-type(2),
div.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.tab:nth-of-type(3),
div.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(4):checked~.tab:nth-of-type(4),
div.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(5):checked~.tab:nth-of-type(5) {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-frame">
<input type="radio" checked name="tab" id="tab1">
<label for="tab1" class="tab-1">Конференции <span>11</span></label>
<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2">
<label for="tab2">Мастер-классы <span>3</span></label>
<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab3">
<label for="tab3">База знаний <span>42</span></label>
<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab5">
<label for="tab5">Курсы <span>2</span></label>
<input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab4">
<label for="tab4">Книги <span>11</span></label>
  
  <div class="tab">
    Конференции
  </div>
  
   <div class="tab">
   Мастер-классы
  </div>
    
  <div class="tab">
   База знаний
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
  Курсы
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">
   Книги
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: [Opening tab with anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678511/opening-tab-with-anchor-link)

Comment: [jQuery tabs с URL анкорами](http://webcoder.kz/jquery-tabs-s-url-ankorami) - первая же ссылка в яндексе, ищите перед тем как спрашивать